# How do you rotate the camera view around a model

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is there any way to rotate the camera around a model by dragging the mouse, especially when editing a model?

I can't find any documentation for Gazebo's mouse and keyboard shortcuts, and playing around with the mouse, I've found I can only pan the view by clicking the dragging, and zooming the view with the mouse scroll bar. I can't find any way to "orbit" around a point, which is a common feature in most CAD systems. Is this possible in Gazebo?

Also, most annoyingly, if I double-click any object, the view immediately switches to a high-up perspective that doesn't let me see any detail, and since I can't rotate the view at all, the only way I can fix it is by going to View->Reset Camera. Why does double clicking a model screw up the camera view?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8409/how-do-you-rotate-the-camera-view-around-a-model/) by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 75 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can orbit the view dragging the mouse wheel pressed. You could also left-click drag while holding the `Shift` key.

Double-clicking a model to zoom in it is a useful feature in several occasions, for example if you have a world with several objects, maybe even moving, and you want to quickly move the view to one of them. But it's true that it might not be useful for every use case, so I created an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/1562/add-option-to-turn-off-zoom-on-model-on) to add an option to turn off this behaviour.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2015-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1031/cerin/) on 2015-04-09**:
Thanks. I'm on a laptop, so I don't have a mouse wheel to press, so I never thought to try that, but the left-click+shift works perfectly.

**Comment by [_sparkle_eyes](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11820/_sparkle_eyes/) on 2019-05-27**:
Thanks, this helps! Can't upvote since my account is new...

**Comment by [HaFred](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/59673/hafred/) on 2021-10-25**:
It definitely works! Funny thing is that in the tutorial they did not cover such a basic operation for rotation :)